# Failed to notify dependency resolution listener - IONIC 4 Build

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to build an IONIC 4 application through the command `ionic cordova build android --release`. The build fails at the end which shows the following errors which I have marked red in the screen shot. I even tried to comment out those `com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-common`. But the error still displays, I have searched different communities, but was unable to find a solution.

[image]

Comment: try this - https://codefranxx.blogspot.com/2019/10/solved-google-services-version-conflict.html

Comment: have you tried modifying the projec.properties in /platforms/android/project.properties with the versions suggested ? When compiling in dev mode, it shows the same error?